# How can I use xkvltxp to allow macros in key-value fixme package options?

Tags: errors, packages, xkeyval, fixme

Following the instructions in `fixme`'s documentation, I load the `xkvltxp` package to allow the use of macros as values in key-value package options.

However, I get an error if I actually use something in the document which depends on that option. For example,

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{xkvltxp}
\usepackage[draft,envface=\itshape]{fixme}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\kant[1]
\fxfatal{thing}
\begin{anfxfatal}{other thing}
  \kant[2]
\end{anfxfatal}
\end{document}
```

gives the error

```
FiXme Fatal Error: 'other thing' on input line 150.

! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.150 \begin{anfxfatal}{other thing}

? h
Please don't say `\def cs{...}', say `\def\cs{...}'.
I've inserted an inaccessible control sequence so that your
definition will be completed without mixing me up too badly.
You can recover graciously from this error, if you're
careful; see exercise 27.2 in The TeXbook.
```

The error does not occur when the package is loaded, or when `\fxfatal` is used, but only when - and if - the `anfxfatal` environment, which the `envface` option influences, is used in the document.

What am I doing wrong?

*Note that I know how to workaround this error. I am asking specifically how to do this correctly so that `\usepackage[envface=\itshape]{fixme}` works and not how to make the typeface italic in `fixme` environments.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `xkvltxp` package redefines `\@fileswith@pti@ns` to allow for control sequences, but unfortunately uses `\edef`, so commands such as `\itshape` are definitely not allowed.

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{xkvltxp}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
% fix the error in xkvltxp
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@fileswith@pti@ns}{\edef}{\protected@edef}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@fileswith@pti@ns}{\edef}{\protected@edef}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage[draft,envface=\itshape]{fixme}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\kant[1]
\fxfatal{thing}
\begin{anfxfatal}{other thing}
  \kant[2]
\end{anfxfatal}
\end{document}
```

Instead of using options to the package, I'd prefer the `\fxsetup` strategy:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}

\usepackage[draft]{fixme}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\fxsetup{envface=\itshape}

\begin{document}
\kant[1]
\fxfatal{thing}
\begin{anfxfatal}{other thing}
  \kant[2]
\end{anfxfatal}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The second part of this answer is precisely why I added the caveat to my question ;).